# Quickest way to prevent SQL returning data older than Given

Tags: php, sql, date, where-clause

I have a pretty complex database with loads of different tables for different things, every thing of which has a timestamp (Y-M-D h:m:s format)

Is there a way I can limit my SQL query to just results from a certain timespan, for example a week ago?

If needbe I have a function to convert these timestamps into unix as

```
sqlToUnix($date);
//returns $unixTime
```

so for example

```
mysql_query(SELECT id FROM entries WHERE entries.date >= $formattedDateString);
```

Thanks!

Just a reminder the database dates are of the format: 2009-02-15 08:47:45

Comment: if you are using a datetime field (as oppose to a string representation), then dates do not have a particular format.

Comment: not sure which DBMS you are using but in SQL Server a timestamp column is not a datetime...

Comment: I think it's obvious that the fields ARE in fact DateTime fields, because the conversion-function he posted wouldn't make much sense. Also to answer the question that is not of importance because handling either case works the same ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's totally possible with the BETWEEN-statement (Since MySQL 4.0):

```
mysql_query("SELECT id FROM entries WHERE entries.date BETWEEN 'Y-M-D h:m:s' AND 'Y-M-D h:m:s'");
```

Also, to calculate the timestamp one week before the current date have a look at the [MySQL Online Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: Okay thanks that problem now is that I already have a WHERE parameter, how can I add another one without interfering with the old one? eg &&

Comment: You can have mutliple boolean statements after the where clause by concatenating them with "AND". So for instance: "WHERE id=5 AND date BETWEEN '2009-02-15' AND '2009-02-09'" would check wether the id equals five and the date is within the last week.

Comment: Just append the condition to the end of the current WHERE. If you don't touch the rest of the query, it should not matter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a MSSQL user myself, but looking up online I can see a few usefull pieces of information for MySQL 5.0...

[curdate()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)
[date_add()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

With this you should be able to create a WHERE clause something like...

```
WHERE
   <field> >= date_add(curdate(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)
```

As mentioned elsewhere, if the field is a string, convert it to a date using [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like you have written you can make greater than and lower than restrictions on your output. Where is the problem?

If your field is no timestamp/datetime field but a string, use the MySQL function STR_TO_DATE() (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)